# Twilio: making call w/o own server

Tags: android, rest, twilio, sip-server

Just begin to learn Twilio API. My intention is to make call directly from Android phone to any landline number. I have read QuickStart guide, build  sample Android application and found that to make a call one need to have his own REST server.

I didn't have any experience with any SIP alike apps, but my understanding was that there's SIP provider server through which I could place a call and that's it... (with any kind of authorisation and so on).

So the question: is any possibility to place call using Twilio without my own server? Or as option - could someone advise me 3d party provider of those server which can be used to place call through Twilio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Hey, even better then setting up your own server yourself, you can just head to our [Github repo](https://github.com/twilio/mobile-quickstart) and use the click to deploy button. It requires you to have a Heroku account which you can obviously use for free.

From there, you have your own URL for the application, which you can add to your Android App. So no need to setup your own backend if you don't want to.

The repo takes you through all the steps for configuring your app, but by all means if you have any questions, please do not hesitate in getting back to me.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can we call twilio api directly from android app without using our backend server?

Comment: You can, but that will expose your credentials as anyone can decompile your app. I wrote more about it here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-send-an-sms-from-android.html